# how to get the record on the basis of certain coditions in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to fetch the record with some condtions from two table

```
SELECT `tbui`.`user_id`,    `tbui`.`first_name`,`tbui`.`last_name`,`tbui`.`education_level`,`tbui`.`sex`,`tbui`.`country_of_origin`,`tbui`.`city`,`tbui`.`state`,`tbui`.`country`,`tbui`.`occupation`,`tbui`.`about`,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,`tbui`.`age`,CURDATE()) as age
FROM `tb_preference_dropdown` as `tbpda`
     RIGHT JOIN `tb_user_answers` as `tbua` ON `tbpda`.`question_id` = `tbua`.`question_id`
     RIGHT JOIN `tb_preference_questions` as `tbpa` ON `tbpa`.`user_id` = `tbpda`.`user_id`
     RIGHT JOIN `tb_user_info` as `tbui` ON `tbui`.`user_id` = `tbua`.`user_id`
WHERE `tbpda`.`user_id` = 113 
     AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,`tbui`.`age`,CURDATE()) >=`tbpa`.`min_age_required` AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,`tbui`.`age`,CURDATE()) <= `tbpa`.`max_age_required`
     AND `tbui`.`country_of_origin` = `tbpa`.`country_of_origin` 
     AND `tbua`.`user_id` != 113
     AND `tbui`.`sex` != 'Female'
     HAVING SUM(IF(tbpda.question_id = 1,IF(tbpda.answer_id !=0,IF(tbua.question_id =tbpda.question_id AND `tbua`.`answer_id` = tbpda.answer_id,tbua.user_id,''),true),'')) > 0
```

all the things working perfectly except:

```
HAVING SUM(IF(tbpda.question_id = 1,IF(tbpda.answer_id !=0,IF(tbua.question_id =tbpda.question_id AND `tbua`.`answer_id` = tbpda.answer_id,tbua.user_id,''),true),'')) > 0
```

i am getting the records which even don't match with the above condition

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Switch to left join instead, because it's much easier for humans to understand `main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Your outer joins behave as regular inner joins anyway... Move conditions from WHERE to ON to get true outer join.

Comment: where is group by clause?

Comment: @jarlh can you please suggest me as i am very new to sql

Comment: all conditions are working fine except: 
`HAVING SUM(IF(tbpda.question_id = 1,IF(tbpda.answer_id !=0,IF(tbua.question_id =tbpda.question_id AND tbua.answer_id = tbpda.answer_id,tbua.user_id,''),true),'')) > 0`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @BibinMatthew thanks that's worked for me

Comment: @PandatArun cheers!!

Comment: @BibinMatthew srry,i don't know how to accept your answer so that you earned some point

Comment: I can write it as an answer, you can accept it there @PandatArun

Comment: Explain what your query does.  You just dump a bunch of code here and expect people to understand what you are trying to do??

Comment: @Eric srry i am very new to this platform so i actually don't know the correct way to ask question.
what i want to do with this query is to fetch the record from tb_user_info on the basis of certain conditions which i have mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **GROUP BY** clause, re-write the query